# Help me Checkbox's check mark is hidden 

Tags: iphone, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

Please look at my following code snippet. I place check box in to my cell , i can able to check or uncheck the checkbox. but when i scroll the table view the checkbox's check mark is getting hidden.
i mean i set the check mark by setting the image.

Please anybody help me to solve this problem.

Thanks for your time.

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

      if (cell == nil)
      {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"en"] autorelease];

      cb = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,10, unselectedImage.size.width, unselectedImage.size.height)];

    [cb setImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cb setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [cb addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cb];

    }

    if ( tableView == myTableView )
    {
      titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 0, 150, 35)];
      titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
      titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];  
      [cell.contentView addSubview:titleLabel];

      cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator; 
    }

      return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=793715)

If I understand the TableView concept correctly, you need to save the checkmark setting somewhere else. If your cell gets scrolled out of view the TableViewController might release the cell. Then, when you're asked to re-create the cell in your delegate, you have to restore it in the same state as before.

Answer (score 0):

In `DidSelectRowAtindexPath`:

```
if ([set containsObject:indexPath]) 
{
    [set removeObject:indexPath];
}
else 
{
    [set addObject:indexPath];
}
```

and in `CellForRpwAtIndexPath`:

```
if ([set containsObject:indexPath]) 
{
    cell.imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"chealBox1.png"];
}
else 
{
    cell.imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"chealBox2.png"];
}
```

here set is `NSMutableSet` and you have to make property and synthesize and alloc as well in viewDidLoad...will work definitely...